# dynamically merging(override) 2 javascript objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 objects .

```
userprofile = {
  id: 1,
  email: hello @gmail.com,
  user: {
    id: 1,
    username: test,
  }

}

userprofile2 = {
  email: bye @gmail.com,
  user: {
    username: testtest,
  }
}
```

What i wish to do is to merge `userprofile` and `userprofile2` , or in a sense using `userprofile2` to override `userprofile`.

Here is what i wish to obtain:

```
updatedprofile = {
  id: 1,
  email: bye @gmail.com,
  user: {
    id: 1,
    username: testtest,
  }
}
```

The application for this problem is because i have an update form which uses `redux saga` . The change in data is `userprofile2` while the previous data is `userprofile`.

Is there a simple efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the spread operator. As the `...` operator only performs a shallow merge, you will have to spread the nested `user` property as well.

```js
const userprofile = {
  id: 1,
  email: "hello @gmail.com",
  user: {
    id: 1,
    username: "test",
  }

}

const userprofile2 = {
  email: "bye @gmail.com",
  user: {
    username: "testtest",
  }
}

const updatedProfile = {
   ...userprofile,
   ...userprofile2,

   user: {
     ...userprofile.user,
     ...userprofile2.user,
   }
};

console.log(updatedProfile)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also spread `userprofile.user` and `userprofile2.user`?

Comment: It is already being done.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce OP's required output.

Comment: In fact, it throws an error

Comment: That is because, the OP has not enclosed the value in quotes ( email and username)

Comment: Yeah, that's one error but your code still doesn't work. Try to execute it.

Comment: included a snippet

Comment: Now it works because you're spreading the `userprofile.user` and `userprofile2.user`. Previously you were not doing that.

Comment: oh right. My bad.